# sum of 5 prime numbers equal to 500

Tags: c#, math, primes

I need to create an algorithm that calculates all combinations of **5** prime numbers that *add up* to **500**.
There should be **4088** combinations but my code generates only 3933 combinations and when I remove the conditions that breaks the cycle I get even less combinations and I don´t know why.

I have these instructions:

In any programming language, compile a program that (algorithmically, not with a "magic constant") finds out the number of ways in which it is possible to write the number `500` as the sum of five prime numbers. The output of the program will always be a line of found prime numbers making up the given sum, followed by the total number of found combinations on the last line below the list. The order of the prime numbers does not matter, as long as there are only swapped positions of the same numbers in the combination, it is still one and the same result.
The program should be universal, i.e. it should also be functional when the required sum is changed.

i used following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace součet_prv
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> vysledky= new List<string>();
            List<int> prvocisla= new List<int>();            
            prvocisla = prvocislo();
            vysledky = soucet(prvocisla);
            vypis(vysledky);
        }
        static List<int> prvocislo()
        {
            int x = 500;
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++)
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++)
            {
                for (int y = i * 2; y <= x; y += i)
                {
                    list.Remove(y);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
        static List<string> soucet(List<int>cisla)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int c = 0;
            int d = 0;
            int e = 0;
            while (e < cisla.Count)
            {
                if (cisla[a] + cisla[b] + cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e] > 500)
                {
                    break;
                }
                while (d < cisla.Count)
                {
                    if (cisla[a] + cisla[b] + cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e] > 500)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    while (c < cisla.Count)
                    {
                        if (cisla[a] + cisla[b] + cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e] > 500)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        while (b<cisla.Count)
                        {
                            if (cisla[a] + cisla[b] + cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e] > 500)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            while (a < cisla.Count)
                            {

                                if (cisla[a] + cisla[b] + cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e] > 500)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                if (cisla[a] + cisla[b] + cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e]==500)
                                {
                                    list.Add(cisla[a] + "+" + cisla[b] + "+" + cisla[c] + "+" + cisla[d] + "+" + cisla[e] + "= 500");                                   
                                }
                                a++;
                            }                   
                            b++;
                            a = b;
                        }                       
                        c++;
                        b = c;
                    }
                    d++;
                    c = d;
                }
                e++;
                d = e;
            }
            return list;
        }
        static void vypis(List<string> vysledky)
        {
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("vypis.txt"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < vysledky.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(vysledky[i]);
                }
                sw.WriteLine(vysledky.Count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignoring that there are numerous improvements to make here, I'd suggest you think about what value is in `a` at the point immediately after `c++; b = c;`

Comment: Note, that all prime numbers are *odd* except `2`; so `p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 == 500` means that `p1 == 2` and `p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 == 498`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - that was one of my initial thoughts but the last part of the instructions are "_The program should be universal, i.e. it should also be functional when the required sum is changed._", so you can't guarantee an even number as the sum.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: @DanielMasek Given <not with a "magic constant">, the code only attempts to work for 5 primes.  Should it instead work for `n`  primes to meet your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we can slightly simplify the problem: since *all* primes are *odd* except for `2` then

```
p0 + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 == 500
```

means

```
p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 == 498
```

where `p0 == 2`. Then we can try *brute force* for the rest `p1, ..., p4` primes. We obtain all the prime numbers:

```
private static List<int> Primes(int maxValue) {
  List<int> result = new List<int>() { 2 };

  for (int number = 3; number <= maxValue; number += 2) {
    bool isPrime = true;

    foreach (int divisor in result) {
      var (q, r) = int.DivRem(number, divisor);

      if (r == 0) {
        isPrime = false;

        break;
      }

      if (q < divisor)
        break;
    }

    if (isPrime)
      result.Add(number);
  }

  return result;
}
```

And loop:

```
int target = 500;

List<int> primes = Primes(target);

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < primes.Count; ++i1)
  for (int i2 = i1; i2 < primes.Count; ++i2)
    for (int i3 = i2; i3 < primes.Count; ++i3)
      for (int i4 = i3; i4 < primes.Count; ++i4)
        if (primes[i1] + primes[i2] + primes[i3] + primes[i4] == target - 2)
          Console.WriteLine($"2 + {primes[i1]} + {primes[i2]} + {primes[i3]} + {primes[i4]} == {target}");
```

Output (**4088** lines):

```
2 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 491 == 500
2 + 2 + 2 + 7 + 487 == 500
2 + 2 + 2 + 31 + 463 == 500
2 + 2 + 2 + 37 + 457 == 500
2 + 2 + 2 + 61 + 433 == 500
2 + 2 + 2 + 73 + 421 == 500
...
2 + 113 + 127 + 127 + 131 == 500
```

If you want *distinct* primes then modify the loops:

```
int target = 500;

List<int> primes = Primes(target);

for (int i1 = 1; i1 < primes.Count; ++i1)
  for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < primes.Count; ++i2)
    for (int i3 = i2 + 1; i3 < primes.Count; ++i3)
      for (int i4 = i3 + 1; i4 < primes.Count; ++i4)
        if (primes[i1] + primes[i2] + primes[i3] + primes[i4] == target - 2)
          Console.WriteLine($"2 + {primes[i1]} + {primes[i2]} + {primes[i3]} + {primes[i4]} == {target}");
```

Output (**3611** lines):

```
2 + 3 + 5 + 11 + 479 == 500
2 + 3 + 5 + 23 + 467 == 500
2 + 3 + 5 + 29 + 461 == 500
2 + 3 + 5 + 41 + 449 == 500
...
2 + 107 + 113 + 127 + 151 == 500
2 + 109 + 113 + 127 + 149 == 500
2 + 109 + 113 + 137 + 139 == 500
```

Comment: Note about general usage: `if (divisor * divisor > number)` risks buffer overflow for prime `number` near `INT_MAX`.  Consider `if (divisor > number/divisor)`.  It does not overflow and the divide time cost is often "free" when a good compiler pairs it with nearby `number % divisor`.

Comment: @chux: Thank you very much! Your suggestion doesn't overflow provides a free meal with computing quotient and remainder in one go. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I dunno about providing a complete program as an answer to a question of this nature. The task is less about actually getting the list of numbers and more about learning how to solve problems. What I often do for problems of this kind is to provide hints to help the person asking to think about the problem, and hopefully to get to a solution for themselves. FWIW & YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your code. Here is your code
And result is **4088**

```
while (e < cisla.Count)
        {
            if (cisla[e] > 500)
            {
                break;
            }
            d = e
            while (d < cisla.Count)
            {
                if (cisla[d] + cisla[e] > 500)
                {
                    break;
                }
                c = d
                while (c < cisla.Count)
                {
                    if (cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e] > 500)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    b = c
                    while (b<cisla.Count)
                    {
                        if (cisla[b] + cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e] > 500)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        a = b
                        while (a < cisla.Count)
                        {

                            if (cisla[a] + cisla[b] + cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e] > 500)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            if (cisla[a] + cisla[b] + cisla[c] + cisla[d] + cisla[e]==500)
                            {
                                list.Add(cisla[a] + "+" + cisla[b] + "+" + cisla[c] + "+" + cisla[d] + "+" + cisla[e] + "= 500");                                   
                            }
                            a++;
                        }                   
                        b++;
                    }                       
                    c++;
                }
                d++;
            }
            e++;
        }
```